# How to say "interrogative mood"? Is it "modus interrogativum"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammarians

I'm curious as to how to say "interrogative mood" in Latin. Is it *modus interrogativum*?

Comment: Can you explain what the "interrogative mood" is? The current answer translates that literally, but there may be a better translation for the concept.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [_" Most (...) languages do not have a special mood for asking questions, but exceptions include Welsh, Nenets and Eskimo languages such as Greenlandic."_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood#Interrogative) So this might be a term one could use in a grammar of those languages, if it were written in Latin (as the old Jesuit Fathers used to do).

Answer (score 3):

Were it such a thing, it would be *modus interrogativus*, since *modus* is masculine.

Lewis & Short II.B.3 contains the examples for using *modus* as a classification for verbs:

> 3. In gram., a form of a verb, a voice or mood: “in verbo fiunt soloecismi per genera, tempora, personas, modos, etc.,” Quint. 1, 5, 41: patiendi modus (the passive voice) ... faciendi modus (the active voice), id. 9, 3, 7; cf. 1, 6, 26.

Comment: I wonder if the questioner is confusing the concept of interrogative sentences with mood?  (I found [this link](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0007:part=4:chapter=56) which might help clarify, at least in regards to Greek)